# Проверка на количество измененных символов

Tags: php, проверка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
необходимо реализовать алгоритм сравнения двух строк - разница не должна превышать 2 символа (изменение регистра не считается).

Что сделал:

1. Перевожу все буквы в нижний регистр. Разбиваю строки на массив.
2. Если разница длин массив > 2 - ошибка
3. Если количество измененных символов > 4 (удали 2, добавили 3; заменили 2 символа, один добавили и т.д.) - ошибка

Код реализован на примере PHP:

```
$oldValue = preg_split('//u', (mb_strtolower($oldValue)),-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$newValue = preg_split('//u', (mb_strtolower($newValue))), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);                                    
if(abs((count($oldValue) - count($newValue))) > 2
  || count(array_diff($newValue, $oldValue)) + count(array_diff($oldValue ,$newValue)) > 4) {
       throw new Exception('bla-bla');
}
```

Успешно отрабатывает на парах:

```
Ивановвввв -> Иванов (Exception)
Иванов -> Иванв
Иванов -> Иван
иИванов -> Иванов
ииванова -> Иванов
Иванокк -> Иванов
Пелоге -> Пелагея
```

Но не корректно работает на парах:

```
Пелашш -> Пелагея
```

Кто-то уже сталкивался с подобным родом задачами?

Как найти оптимальное решение без перечисления всех возможных кейсов?

Comment: почему бы не использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcasecmp.php ?

Comment: А ну да, проверил на примерах, если разница в центре выдает > 2. Может быть поможет similar_text, levenshtein или soundex. Но там уже в процентах.Либо есть отдельных экстеншен http://pear.horde.org/ там большая либа для этого.

Comment: *разница не должна превышать 2 символа (изменение регистра не считается)* Что речь о расстоянии Левенштейна - Вы поняли, это хорошо. Правда, непонятно, согласны ли Вы с набором операций, использованных в этой реализации функции. Потому как *при кейсе Пелашш -> Пелагея - говорит, то количество переходом 3* правильно: (Пелашш -> (замена) -> Пела**г**ш -> (замена) -> Пелаг**е** -> (добавление) -> Пелаге**я**).